# Google MAPS API V3 --> How to display all the Polygons that are stored in my MYSQL table?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty new on google MAPS API V3 and I like to get some help. 
 I'm drawing polygons on my site and it works fine. I save the coordinates of my Polygons on a MYSQL database, and here is the structure of the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `localite` (
  `id_localite` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `libele_localite` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat_localite` text NOT NULL,
  `long_localite` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_localite`)
)
```

as you can see I have devided the lats and longs into seperate columns and I get the coordinates using PHP ..

the lat_localite Column contains just the Latitude coordinates, and the long_localite Column contains just the longitude coordinates , I get this coordinates by using Javascript and writing the content in 2 seperate textareas .. this is the code:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
  var patths = polygon.getPath();
  var stuh = patths.getLength();
    var lat_localite='';
    var long_localite='';
        for (var i=0; i<(stuh) ;i++)
        {
        lat_localite  += (patths.getAt(i).lat()+'\n');
        long_localite += (patths.getAt(i).lng()+'\n');

        document.forms['formId'].elements['Textarea1ID'].value=lat_localite;
        document.forms['formId'].elements['Textarea2ID'].value=long_localite;

        }   
});
```

SO now  I Want to display all the Polygons that are stored in my table AND i don't know How to do it Can You Help me ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display the numeric values associated with the points that make up all of your polygons? Or, that you want to re-draw the polygons on the map after retrieving the data?

Answer (score 3):

With V3 it's quite easy.

```
var polygons = [];
```

And then just loop through all your polyongs from database with the following code.

```
  //Add all your coordinates in with new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  var coords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(12.5, -8.2),
    new google.maps.LatLng(12.52, -8.21),
    etc....
  ];

  // Construct the polygon
  polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coords,
    other_options: etc....
  }));

  polygons[polygons.length-1].setMap(map); //Your map object
```

Secondly (out of interest), MySql can store Polygons using Spatial Data Types (look at [Polygon data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html))

This can help if you need to query the data. You are restriected to minimum bounding rectangles but I think this data type is better for .

To extract the polygon from MySql as lat/lng coordinates look at mysql's AsText() function.

eg:

```
select AsText(my_polygon_column) as blob;
```

And then pass that through this php function:

```
function sql_to_coordinates($blob)
    {
        $blob = str_replace("))", "", str_replace("POLYGON((", "", $blob));
        $coords = explode(",", $blob);
        $coordinates = array();
        foreach($coords as $coord)
        {
            $coord_split = explode(" ", $coord);
            $coordinates[]=array("lat"=>$coord_split[0], "lng"=>$coord_split[1]);
        }
        return $coordinates;
    }
```